# ImportError: cannot import name is_python_keyword

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to execute a python script , but I get an error on line

```
from jinja2.utils import Markup, concat, escape, is_python_keyword, next
```

ImportError: cannot import name is_python_keyword

I checked there is no file named is_python.py

Comment: The complaint is is_python_keyword does not exist in jinja2.utils How do you want to import something that does not exist? It should complaint as it does

Comment: is there a way to see the list of available classes that i can import ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](http://svn.python.org/projects/external/Jinja-2.3.1/jinja2/utils.py) for 2.3.1 they have a line:

```
from keyword import iskeyword as is_python_keyword
```

They are using the builtin `keyword` module.

The current version is 2.7.3 so it seems they have changed the code and it is no longer available.

You could use the above import from the builtin module instead.

Comment: I get a similar error in debug.py as well when I try to do a 
from jinja2.utils import CodeType

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar Why are you trying to `import CodeType`?